# Remove customDimensions items from Application Insights when using opencensus-python

Tags: python, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, opencensus

In [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python) on how to use `opencensus-python` to submit traces to Azure Application Insights, it's spelled out how to add additional information to the `customDimensions` field. That is,

```py
import logging

from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(
    connection_string='InstrumentationKey=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
)

logger.error('blooh')
logger.error('blooh2', extra={'custom_dimensions': {'woot': 42}})
```

becomes

[image]

in the Application Insights UI.

That's all well and good, but what is the intended way to remove the items from `customDimensions` that are included by default; i.e. things like `fileName` and `process`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [inspection of the source code](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/blob/511289fa4cc4bbd6e013c8a33c5dc570a895ed2c/contrib/opencensus-ext-azure/opencensus/ext/azure/log_exporter/__init__.py#L158), the properties do seem rather hard to avoid to create, but it is possible to remove them by post-processing the `envelope`:

```py
import logging

from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

custom_dimensions = {'foo': 'bar'}

def remove_items(envelope):
    envelope.data.baseData.properties = custom_dimensions
    return True

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = AzureLogHandler(connection_string='InstrumentationKey=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
handler.add_telemetry_processor(remove_items)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.error('blooh')
```

This is tested and works in `opencensus-ext-azure` version 1.0.5.

[image]

Notice also that with this approarch, it is no longer necessary to specify the `extra` when logging.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution where you can still supply the custom_dimensions in `logger.error()` at execution time:

```
import logging
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler
    
def remove_items(envelope):
    for k in ['process', 'module', 'fileName', 'lineNumber', 'level']: 
        envelope.data.baseData.properties.pop(k)
    return True

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = AzureLogHandler(connection_string='InstrumentationKey=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
handler.add_telemetry_processor(remove_items)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.error('blooh', custom_dimensions={'foo': 'bar'})
```